# How to read lines of data from multiple files

Tags: bash

I need to extract data from files in directory `/tmp/log`.
I have no problem extract from single file.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line;
do
  echo $line
done < /tmp/log/file1
```

I want try it with multiple files `/tmp/log/*` but it returned error `ambiguous redirect`.
Any idea how can I around it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could read the files in a for loop as follows:

```
for file in /tmp/log/*; do
    while read -r line; do
        echo "$line"
    done < "$file"
done
```

The strategy is just wrap your while loop with a for loop that takes care of processing each of the files one at a time.

Comment: It is interesting loop where for loop supply file to while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know exactly waht you need..
probably you are looking for this:

```
cat /tmp/log/*
```

Is this what you need?

```
for line in `cat /tmp/log/*`
do     
echo $line     
done
```

Comment: It does do the work but I want to process the data line by line

Comment: In this case, you could use a process substitution: `while read line; do ...; done < <(cat /tmp/log/*)`